# How to search for a substring in a string in iOS automation scripting? indexOf() and search() methods are not working

Tags: javascript, ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

How to search for a ***substring in a string in iOS automation scripting***? indexOf() and search() methods are not working.

Comment: try to use a regex. do you want to check the presents of the substring or has to get the location of the substring

Comment: i want to check the presence of the substring.. can you please elaborate as to which regex i can use?

Comment: What error message do you get in your trace log? search and indexOf both seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().staticTexts()[0].value();
var index = text.indexOf("text that looking for");
UIALogger.logDebug("index is: " + i); // -1 means not found
```

It have been tested.